# Problem with sizing side-by-side minipages

Tags: horizontal-alignment, line-breaking, minipage

I've been writing up my resume in LaTeX (for the flashiness and also to get better with LaTeX), and I've been having some trouble with one of the macros I wrote, called `\nrccolstring`.

`\nrccolstring` is supposed to take two text fields and make them into side-by-side  miniboxes that span all of the space allocated for them. The first minibox is left-justified, and the second minibox is right-justified.

My macro works great when it's on the whole page, but it craps out on me when I nest it inside another minibox (such as the one I'm currently using to control columns).

When I run the attached code, I get the following output: [image]

So what's up?

Why does it fail on the second macro? I get a couple of warnings (shown below), but the document compiles fine.

```
  Overfull \hbox (2.22221pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 33--34<br>
  Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 33--34
```

What's going on here? There's clearly something I don't understand about how the sizing of a minipage works.

Should I be using something other than miniboxes to achieve the effect?

I thought about using columns or a table originally, but I wanted something that would automatically size the cells to take the entire `\textwidth` and also make sure that the cells are wide enough (assuming the overall `\textwidth` is big enough to fit everything).

Thoughts?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[top=0.5in, bottom=0.5in, left=0.5in, right=0.5in]{geometry}

\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{blindtext}

%----------------------- Registers-----------------------------%
\newlength{\registera}
\newlength{\registerb}
%-------------------- Text Field Macros-------------------------%
\newcommand{\CompanyName}{This is a Fictional Company Name}
\newcommand{\Description}{\blindtext}

%-------------------- Formatting Macros------------------------%

\newcommand{\nrccolstring}[2]{
    \begingroup
    \setlength{\registera}{\widthof{\noindent \raggedright #1}}%
    \setlength{\registerb}{\dimexpr \textwidth - \registera \relax}%
    \noindent \begin{minipage}[t]{\registera}
        \noindent \raggedright #1\\ 
    \end{minipage}
    \noindent \begin{minipage}[t]{\registerb}
        \noindent \raggedleft #2\\
    \end{minipage}
\endgroup}

%------------------------ Body Text ---------------------------%

\begin{document}
    \blindtext
    \par \bigskip
    \par\nrccolstring{\textbf{\CompanyName}}{2011-Present} % Macro works here!
    \par
    \Description
    \par \bigskip

    \noindent \begin{minipage}[t]{0.5\textwidth}
        \par\nrccolstring{\textbf{\CompanyName}}{2011-Present}  % Macro doesn't work here!
        \par
        \Description
    \end{minipage}
    \noindent \begin{minipage}[t]{0.5\textwidth}
        \Description
    \end{minipage}
\end{document}
```

Comment: You have some spurious spaces within your definition of `\nrccolstring`, as well as the part you say "Macro doesn't work here". Also, you shouldn't end any paragraph with a `\\`. Is the intent just to have a macro that sets something in two parts (one on the left, the other on the right)?

Comment: Yeah, that's the intended purpose of the macro. Is something nicer for doing that kind of thing? (1/3)

Comment: This is going to sound dumb (I'm a dumb guy) but can you point me at the line number (or cut/paste) an example of the faulty paragraph? I'm not sure which part you meant by that. (2/3)

Comment: Also, I guess I thought LaTeX generally ignored whitespace - how can I fix my macro and keep it readable? (3/3)

Comment: @NicholasClark Would be better to use multicol for the two column part, i.e., create an environment rather than macros and minipages.

Comment: @YiannisLazarides Is it easy to control the width of multicol's columns? I'd hate to have to tweak them every time a text string exceeds some hard-coded column width.

Comment: @NicholasClark I think it is easier. Will post an answer tonight.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an updated version of your current document:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[top=0.5in, bottom=0.5in, left=0.5in, right=0.5in]{geometry}% http://ctan.org/pkg/geometry
\usepackage{calc,blindtext}% http://ctan.org/pkg/{calc,blindtext}

%----------------------- Registers-----------------------------%
\newlength{\registera}
\newlength{\registerb}
%-------------------- Text Field Macros-------------------------%
\newcommand{\CompanyName}{This is a Fictional Company Name}
\newcommand{\Description}{\blindtext}

%-------------------- Formatting Macros------------------------%

\newcommand{\nrccolstring}[2]{%
  \begingroup
  \setlength{\registera}{\widthof{#1}}%
  \setlength{\registerb}{\dimexpr \linewidth - \registera \relax}%
  \noindent\begin{minipage}[t]{\registera}
    \raggedright #1
  \end{minipage}%
  \begin{minipage}[t]{\registerb}
    \raggedleft #2
  \end{minipage}%
\endgroup}

%------------------------ Body Text ---------------------------%

\begin{document}
  \blindtext\par
  \bigskip
  \nrccolstring{\textbf{\CompanyName}}{2011-Present} % Macro works here!
  \par
  \Description\par
  \bigskip

  \noindent \begin{minipage}[t]{\dimexpr0.5\textwidth-0.5\columnsep}
    \nrccolstring{\textbf{\CompanyName}}{2011-Present}  % Macro doesn't work here!
    \par\Description
  \end{minipage}\hfill%
  \begin{minipage}[t]{\dimexpr0.5\textwidth-0.5\columnsep}
    \Description
  \end{minipage}
\end{document}
```

Most notable changes include:

- Using `%` to remove spurious spaces; LaTeX does ignore spaces in *math* mode, but not in text mode. It does ignore consecutive spaces, but single spaces are still visible/set. See [What is the use of percent signs (`%`) at the end of lines?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/7453/5764)
- Using `\linewidth` instead of `\textwidth`. This allows for setting your `\nrccolstring` inside a `minipage` without it spilling over the box boundary.
- Removing `\\` at the end of a paragraph.

Comment: Wow.  You beat me to this by 9 seconds.  LOL.  Pretty much the same comments too.  :)

Comment: Ah, I see what you mean about the spaces and the `\\ `. Thanks! One other question about this funky macro - if I call `\nrccolstring` inside of a `minipage` which is too small for the whole `\nrccolstring` to fit on one line, the left-side field doesn't seem to linebreak properly (even if I modify the macro so that #2 controls the minipage sze). Any thoughts on why?

Comment: Never mind - I found my problem: I had field #1 in `\underline` and it killed the linebreak. Thanks for the help! Any tricks to make `\underline` play nicely as input to the macro?

Comment: @NicholasClark: `\underline` doesn't allow for line breaks. You could consider using [`ulem`](http://ctan.org/pkg/ulem). However, having **boldfaced** entries already highlights it sufficiently, in my opinion.

Comment: @Werner I'd vote you up but I don't have the rep yet! Thanks again.